# Prepping strings for CURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm using CURL in PHP like so:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{"value\":\"$content\"}"
```

etc.

This works fine when `$content` is a very simple string, but when it's a multi-line or has special characters, it gets rejected.

So I did: `$content = curl_escape($curl, $content_1);`

This worked great for even those more complex strings, however, it returned a completely encoded "blob" of HTML. This wouldn't normally be a problem, but the content is being directly sent via email so I can't decode it before sending. Is there another way to get these strings safe without completely encoding everything?

Comment: If you're trying to send JSON, use `json_encode()` to format it correctly.

Comment: @Barmar It's for sendgrid and their documentation is kinda terrible, so I'm not sure what it wants. Are you saying to `json_encode()` everything I send in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` or just `$content`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode()` to create a JSON parameter.

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array('value' => $content))
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I oversimplifed my example, the full format is actually like this: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/232#issuecomment-228908456, so there are more parameters that need to be included. How can I combine all of this?

Comment: Just make a multi-dimensional PHP array that contains all the parameters. `json_encode()` will handle all the formatting.